# Having the nth char based on a variable not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

So I have `pow` - a list containing numbers. I have to examine other numbers like this: Get all the digits and sum the numbers from `pow` having the same index as the certain digit.

So if I check number `4552` I need to get `pow[4]+pow[5]+pow[5]+pow[2]`. Because I'm a noob I try to convert the number to `string`, get the characters with loop and then convert back to `int` to get the index. So the code is as follows for getting the sums between 4550 and 4559:

```
        for (int i = 4550; i < 4560; i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < i.ToString().Length; j++)
            {
                sum += pows[Convert.ToInt32(i.ToString()[j])]; //here is the error - index was out of range
                //do something with sum (like store it in another list)
            }
        }
```

So what is wrong with that?

**EDIT**: To avoid confusion... `pow` has 10 elements, from indexes 0-9.

**SOLUTION**: The issue with my code was that I got the character code not the digit itself, thanks **Steve Lillis**. Though the solution provided by **Dmitry Bychenko** is far more superior to my attempt. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is similar to a [digital root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root):

Modulus (`%` in C#) is easier and faster than *conversion to string*:

```
public static int DigitalRootIndex(IList<int> list, int value) {
  if (value < 0)
    value = -value;

  int result = 0;

  // for value == 4552
  // result == list[4] + list[5] + list[5] + list[2]
  while (value > 0) {
    int index = value % 10;
    result += list[index];
    value /= 10;
  }

  return result;
}

...

int test = DigitalRootIndex(pow, 4552);
```

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code gets a single character such as '4' which is character code 59:

```
c = i.ToString()[j]
```

Then this bit of code turns that char into an integer.  It doesn't parse it like you're expecting, so the result for '4' is 59, not 4:

```
Convert.ToInt32(c)
```

Do this instead:

```
int.Parse(c.ToString())
```

Comment: Wow this is strange. It died again with the same error when tried `sum += ...` but I put a `console.writeline(x);` and got 49 (?!)

Comment: Updated my answer because I just realised what's happening :)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this (quick and dirty try)?

```
        int currentDigit;
        int sum;
        for (int i = 4550; i < 4560; i++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            currentDigit = i;
            while (currentDigit > 0)
            {
                if (pow.Count > (currentDigit % 10))
                {
                    sum += pow[((currentDigit % 10))];
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that lists have zero based index so when you do pow[1], you are actually accessing second element in the list. Is that what you want?